# Making text urls clickable in a div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to make url's clickable in my react application. My current approach is as follows.

```
render() {

  function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
      return '<a href="' + url + '">' + '</a>';
    })
  }

  const headingAvailable = (
    <span className="home_post_text">{urlify(postData.heading)}</span>
  );

  return (
    <div className="home_post_sections sec2 unchange_div">{headingAvailable}</div>
  );
}
```

But i cannot get this to work correctly.

**For example :**

if my text is something like this

`this is a good song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9wBXC3aZ_I&index=8&list=RDxuAH21DkJow`

My text is converted to something like this

`this is a good song <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9wBXC3aZ_I&index=8&list=RDxuAH21DkJow"></a>`

**How can i fix this ?**

Comment: According to your example, you might be wanting to return the following? 
                return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url +  '</a>';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React escapes html tags in strings by default, in order to prevent **XSS** security flaws.

You need to return an `a` component, something like that:

```
render() {

  function urlify(text) {
    const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.split(urlRegex)
       .map(part => {
          if(part.match(urlRegex)) {
             return <a href={part}>{part}</a>;
          }
          return part;
       });
  }

  const headingAvailable = (
    <span className="home_post_text">{urlify(postData.heading)}</span>
  );

  return (
    <div className="home_post_sections sec2 unchange_div">{headingAvailable}</div>
  );
}
```

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.text = 'this is a good song https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9wBXC3aZ_I&index=8&list=RDxuAH21DkJow';
  }

  urlify(text) {
    const urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.split(urlRegex)
      .map(part => {
        if (part.match(urlRegex)) {
          return <a href={part} key={part}> {part} </a>;
        }
        return part;
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div> {this.urlify(this.text)} </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Hello name = "World" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract your `link text` from your original text and add it between your `<a>` tags.

```
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        var linkText = text.replace(url, '')
      return '<a href="' + url + '">' + linkText + '</a>';
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change return of urlify function to this

```
return text
          .replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
             return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url +'</a>';
           })
```