# Making links in the text of a div clickable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hyperlink, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make URLs in a text clickable using Nuxt/Vue.

The input text is:
`Learning Outside the Box - https://learningoutsidethebox.com`

I have a method that converts it to a link:

```js
setLinks(text) {
  var Rexp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!:,.;]*)([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?\/=~_|!:,.;]*)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
              
  return text.replace(Rexp, "<NuxtLink to='$1' target='_blank'>$1</NuxtLink>");
}
```

After that I get a result: `Learning Outside the Box - <NuxtLink to='https://learningoutsidethebox.com' target='_blank'>https://learningoutsidethebox.com</NuxtLink>`. But it is still not clickable.

Changing  to `<a>` didn't solve the problem.

Could you please clarify, what should I do to make this text become a working link?

Comment: Generating it as text will indeed not make it Vue-capable. Why are you even using this regex at the first place? Can't you pass the value dynamically? What is `setLinks`?

Comment: 1) Why are you even using this regex at the first place? - used it as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899107/making-text-urls-clickable-in-a-div 2)Could you clarify, where should I pass it? It's a content of a post created by user? setLinks substitutes a URL with a link

Comment: `<nuxt-link :to="dataComingFromTheUser"></nuxt-link>` should be enough actually. If you need to have it massage'd a bit, you could use a `computed`.

Comment: Also, don't use `a` tag for internal links inside of your SPA or you'll need to regenerate it all from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `a` tag and `v-html`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      url: 'Learning Outside the Box - https://learningoutsidethebox.com'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getLink() {
      return this.setLinks(this.url)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setLinks(text) {
      const Rexp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?=~_|!:,.;]*)([-A-Z0-9+&@#%?\/=~_|!:,.;]*)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
      return text.replace(Rexp, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-html="getLink"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I will think about updating my solution since it might cause XSS

Comment: @PavelShepelenko give a read to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69074884/8816585

Comment: Thanks, used `v-dompurify-html` instead of `v-html`